# Pros and cons of length of research stay

Tags: phd, international, visiting

I am a Ph.D. student in the Social Sciences at a German university. I want to apply for an exchange program at a research institute in France, which is very relevant to my research. It is a very big research institute, with ca. 40 senior researchers and ca. 70 Ph.D. students (half of them visiting). The university would provide funds that should cover most (possibly not all) costs related to the stay. I also have some savings that I could use for this. The research stay can last between six and ten months.

I am reflecting on the pros and cons of a shorter vs. longer research stay. I plan to return to Germany for my postdoc phase. The research stay will be in my third year. I would be willing to extend the length of my Ph.D. for a meaningful research stay abroad, but I will have to look for other sources of funding after the end of my third year.

Do you have some advice related to the length of the research stay? Do you think the advantages of a longer research stay would be worth spending a part of my savings or taking longer to graduate?

Comment: I voted to close because this seems like a personal decision that depends details of your situation and individual factors.  That said, if the place you will be visiting has a much more vibrant research community in your area that would allow you to get involved in more collaborations, longer is better all other things equal.

Comment: In my personal experience, six months is a minimum of constructive outcome, considering that issuing you a wifi pass, an entry badge, a weird-paper-you-need-but-not-understand, and finding some housing will take around 2 months.

Answer (score 1):

In academia (being a part of life), everything is unpredictable. I would ask which is harder, lengthening a short stay or shortening a long stay, and then apply for whichever is easier to adjust.

If they are the same, then I would go for the short stay. After you have been there a few months, review this decision, and apply for the longer stay and look for a few months more accommodation if that seems to be wise.

Answer (score 0):

A longer stay would, presumably, give higher probability of reaching some useful, publishable, result. But this might depend on the field. A longer stay might also let you make some stronger connections/collaborations with people there for the future. But that depends on the nature of the interactions generally in your field.

Otherwise, I see no significant difference for a small difference in time.

---

Your added question is too personal for me to give advice. I can't know all of your options.